# Handling DCL ON ERROR actions after first error?

Tags: error-handling, openvms, dcl

The [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [DCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGITAL_Command_Language) command `HELP ON EXAMPLE` displays:

> ON
>
> Examples
>
> ```
>    1.$ ON SEVERE_ERROR THEN CONTINUE
>
>      A command procedure that contains this statement continues
>      to execute normally when a warning or error occurs during
>      execution. When a severe error occurs, the ON statement signals
>      the procedure to execute the next statement anyway. Once
>      the statement has been executed as a result of the severe
>      error condition, the default action (ON ERROR THEN EXIT) is
>      reinstated.
> ```

According to the help if neither `[-]x.for` nor `[-]y.for` exist then the last two lines will not be executed:

```
$ on error then $ continue
$ rename [-]x.for []
$ rename [-]y.for []
$ type *.for
```

Is there a way to set the `ON ERROR` handling as in the first line w/o placing an `ON ERROR` statement  between each line of the script?

Answer (score 4):

If the ON ERROR fires, you have to re-establish it. It looks like you
don't know whether any of the files exists. So the ON ERROR needs to be
re-established after the first failing command.

You can do this in a subroutine, like in:

```
$ on error then $ gosub on_error
$ rename [-]x.for []
$ rename [-]y.for []
$ on error then $ exit
$ type *.for
$ exit
$
$ on_error:
$ on error then $ gosub on_error
$ return
```

Also, you can handle this differently, with disabling error checking (SET
NOON):

```
$ set noon
$ rename [-]x.for []
$ rename [-]y.for []
$ set on
$ type *.for
```

or establishing error handling only for sever errors (ON SEVERE_ERROR):

```
$ on severe_error then $ exit
$ rename [-]x.for []
$ rename [-]y.for []
$ on error then $ exit
$ type *.for
```